# How to get count of Attribute from Json using Typescript

Tags: html, typescript

I am fetching data from JSON. I created a class to map the data.

I have been able to read simple attributes of customer such as Name, Id and Date of Birth. However there are array type of data also in JSON. I want to calculate the number of times a data has occured and also I would like help on how to read data of an array type on JSON.

```
export class Customer {
  id: string;
  address: Address[];
  complaint: Complaint[];
}
class Address {
  addressId: number;
  addressDescription: string;
  address: string;
  city: string;
}
class Complaint {
  complaintId: number;
  startDate: string;
  endDate: string;
}
```

My understanding is that since complaint is an array there can be multiple complaintId so how do I get count of how many complaint Id are there?
I wrote the following code:
    `for (const entry of this.sampleData.complaint) {
        this.complaintCount = i++;`

If I debug  in entry I am getting details of all the attributes present in Complaint.
But now I can't understand how to get count of Complaint Id.

Comment: You will need to modify your Customer class to include a function that sorts complaints into groups with same complaintId, most likely at initialization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `this.sampleData.complaint` is an array then...

```
this.sampleData.complaint.length
```

...will tell you how many items are inside.

Comment: since complaint can be multiple i want to find out how many complaintId are there in total...